# Query to calculate remaining amount

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am looking to create a query that calculates the "Remaining Amount":

Data set and what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

"close" should subtract from the "open" amount and group by "Trade" column.

EDIT:

this is the formula I am trying:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="",,IFERROR(IF(C2:C="close","-",VLOOKUP(A2:A,{IF(C2:C="open",A2:A,""),D2:D},{2},FALSE)-VLOOKUP(A2:A,{IF(C2:C="close",A2:A,""),D2:D},{2},FALSE)),"-")))
```

but it seems to not be returning the right values:

[image]

The return should look like this:

[image]

Comment: Why are there two close amounts for ABC?

Comment: Partial close. I also updated the picture. I put the wrong "remaining amount" values. 

The close values should cancel out the open value once all trades are closed.

Comment: This is the formula I just tried but the calculation seems off:

=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="",,IFERROR(IF(C2:C="close","-",VLOOKUP(A2:A,{IF(C2:C="open",A2:A,""),D2:D},{2},FALSE)-VLOOKUP(A2:A,{IF(C2:C="close",A2:A,""),D2:D},{2},FALSE)),"-")))

Comment: Lets say your sample dataset now has an extra line (in row10) with `Trade 2 - Open - Amount(100)`. Now is this 100 shown in Cell K2 or K10?!  Another one would be what if `Trade 2` did not close out in row 5: Now whats the output values in K2, K3, K5?

Comment: Can only be one open trade per unique ID from column A. Remaining amounts show in the open row only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,if(countif(A2:Σ,Σ)=1,sum(ifna(filter(D2:D*if(C2:C="close",-1,1),A2:A=Σ))),"-"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Works awesome!!